# Translation of the idiom: "To wind (somebody) up"

Tags: traducción, modismos

My question is similar to that of jrdioko's ["to wind up (doing something)"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/translating-to-wind-up-doing-something)

However the expression I'm looking for is: *"To wind (somebody) up"*

I know this is an idiomatic expression so there may or may not be a good translation. In spanish I could say *'molestar'* or *'enojar'* to say that I'm annoying or angering someone but thats not really the meaning I'm looking for.

In English *'to wind someone up'* is to make them tense/nervous/excited (usually on purpose) or to taunt/tease them

Is there a good way to say this or a similar expression in Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more general transaltion would be "provocar" There are a lot of more informal ways to say it, but I'm afraid they're very regional. In Spain you can say:

- Pinchar: When you wind someone up with making fun of them with some offensive or delicate matter for them. You're aiming to make them uncomfortable.
- Chinchar: When you wind someone up in a childish way. You're aiming to exasperate them.
- Picar: Also used when you're trying to provoke so into doing something dangerous or ridiculous.
- Buscar: This one is more used when someone is looking for a brawl. "Si me buscas me vas a encontrar" is a usual way to say someone to stop provoking.

Informal (As Cesar says in comments)

- Tocar las narices.

Highly informal, even rude.

- Tocar los huevos/cojones.

Comment: +1 "Tocar las narices" is also highly informal but not rude.

Comment: @CesarGon right!! I knew I was foregetting something! Added.

Comment: Joder la paciencia